# Is the intersection of two subgroups, defined below, always trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, free-product

Suppose, $G = \mathbb{Z} \ast H$, where $H$ is a torsion-free group. Suppose, $g \in G$ and $g \notin H$.
Is $\langle\langle g \rangle \rangle \cap H$ always trivial?
($\ast$ stands for free product, and $\langle \langle \dots \rangle \rangle$ stands for normal closure)

I failed to construct a counterexample, but I have no idea how to prove this statement too.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try $H=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and use conjugation.

Comment: @Laurent Moret-Bailly, Thank you, but I doubt, that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is torsion-free

Comment: Oops, sorry, I have read too fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\in G$ be the image of $1\in\mathbb{Z}$. Pick some nontrivial $h\in H$, and take $g=aha^{-1}$. Then $g\not\in H$, but $h\in H\cap\langle\langle g\rangle\rangle$.